# Determining whether a grid space is empty in tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have a tkinter project where i am trying to code the sliding puzzle game, so 9 squares, 8 numbered and 1 empty and the if you click one with a number if it can it moves into the empty space. I have used lambda so I have the coordinates but i do not know how to find if the adjacent square is free, is there a way i can do this? Any help is greatly appreciated.

```py
def create_grid(event):
    side = int(math.sqrt(int(size.get())))
    for row in range(side):
        for col in range(side):
            button = Button(window, text = number, command=lambda row=row, col=col: click(row, col))
        button.grid(row=row, column=col)

def click(row, col):
...
```

Comment: You will need to build a list of list for your grid that holds some variable(s) that say if the grid is filled or not and with what. Then you can use index and functions to run checks to see whats there or not and if you can move or not.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
# create the grid
size = 3
grid = [[i for i in range(j*size, (j + 1) * size)] for j in range(size)]
# check if a there is a free location next to a given coordinate
def is_free(x,y):
    assert x >= 0
    assert y >= 0
    assert x < size
    assert y < size
    up = grid[y-1][x]    if y-1 >= 0 else -1
    down = grid[y+1][x]  if y+1 < size else -1
    left = grid[y][x-1]  if x-1 >= 0 else -1
    right = grid[y][x+1] if x+1 < size else -1
    return not up or not down or not left or not right
```

First we create a grid, using 0 as the empty square. Get the values next to the current x,y coordinate (on click I suppose) and finally return whether we found any 0's. You could even return the direction of the free grid location for later use (I imagine you will need it!).

Making this work with your current set up should be straight forward.

Hope this helps!